# Ansible: loop on each item of list ( which is variable itself )

Tags: python, json, loops, ansible, jinja2

I have a list

```
states:
  - california
  - illinois
  - newyork
```

and each item of the list is a variable

```
vars:
  california: west
  illinois: midwest
  newyork: east
```

I want to use loop to debug values of each item in the list,

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ states }}"
```

The above code gives me this output

```
TASK [../../playbook : debug] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=california) => {
    "msg": [
        "california"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=illinois) => {
    "msg": [
        "illinois"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=newyork) => {
    "msg": [
        "newyork"
    ]
}
```

instead i want to display, the value like below

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=california) => {
    "msg": [
        "west"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=illinois) => {
    "msg": [
        "midwest"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=newyork) => {
    "msg": [
        "east"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question and fix the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the [`lookup` plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html)

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ states }}"
```